# Prove that $x+(\overline{x}\cdot\overline{y})=x+\overline{y}$

Tags: boolean-algebra

Prove that $x+(\overline{x}\cdot\overline{y})=x+\overline{y}$

The values of both these boolean functions show that these 2 are equivalent.

```
$x$  $\overline{x}$  $y$  $\overline{x}\cdot\overline{y}$  $x+(\overline{x}\cdot\overline{y})$  $x+\overline{y}$

0  1  0  0  0  0

0  1  1  1  1  1

1  0  0  0  1  1

1  0  1  0  1  1
```

---

I proved this. Missed the distributive law.
\begin{eqnarray*}
x+(\overline{x}\cdot\overline{y})&=&(x+\overline{x})\cdot(x+\overline{y})\\
&=&1\cdot(x+\overline{y})\\
&=&x+\overline{y}
\end{eqnarray*}

I often find the answer just before or after posting the question to SE.
Don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative solution to Caran's:

$x+\bar y = x+(x+\bar x)\cdot\bar y = (x+x\cdot\bar y) +\bar x\cdot \bar y = x+\bar x\cdot\bar y$

Comment: May be you should parenthesize the last step to cleary show that you have used the absorption law.  $x+x\cdot\overline{y}=x$

Comment: @Sakthi Good point, I edited it. Is it easier to read now?

Answer (score 0):

Using [De Morgan's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) laws one can obtain:
$$x+(\overline{x}\cdot\overline{y})=x+\overline{x+y}=\overline{\overline{x}\cdot \overline{\overline{(x+y)}}}=\overline{\overline{x}\cdot (x+y)}=\overline{\overline{x}\cdot x+\overline{x}\cdot y}=\overline{\overline{x}\cdot y}=\overline{\overline{x}}+\overline{y}=x+\overline{y}$$

Comment: Looks more complicated than my answer.

Comment: @Sakthi there is always a wide variety of answers. Different people - different solutions.

Comment: How is $\overline{\overline{x}+y}=\overline{\overline{x}}+\overline{y}$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Proved this by myself. Missed the distributive law.
\begin{eqnarray*}
x+(\overline{x}\cdot\overline{y})&=&(x+\overline{x})\cdot(x+\overline{y})\\
&=&1\cdot(x+\overline{y})\\
&=&x+\overline{y}
\end{eqnarray*}